# Use Single Common Table Expression With Multiple Statements

Tags: sql, db2

**Database**

Db2

**Scenario**

I have to get a list of `ID`s and `DELETE FROM...` two tables. I get all the `ID`'s from a CTE, but I can only use it on one `DELETE` statement. I have to query the CTE again for the other `DELETE`.

**Current Solution**

```
-- GET A LIST OF ALL CHILDREN OF A NODE, INCLUDING A NODE
WITH NODE_LIST (ID) AS
(
    -- CHILDREN
    SELECT n.ID FROM NODE n WHERE n.ID = '8ae433156f7f4469857e7de205ec4fe0'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n.ID FROM NODE n, NODE_LIST nl WHERE nl.ID = n.PARENT
)
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM OLD TABLE(
    DELETE FROM FIRST_NODE_TABLE ns WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM NODE_LIST nl WHERE nl.ID = ns.CHILD OR nl.ID = ns.PARENT)
);

WITH NODE_LIST (ID) AS
(
    SELECT n.ID FROM NODE n WHERE n.ID = '8ae433156f7f4469857e7de205ec4fe0'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n.ID FROM NODE n, NODE_LIST nl WHERE nl.ID = n.PARENT
)

SELECT COUNT (*) FROM OLD TABLE(
    DELETE FROM SECOND_NODE_TABLE n WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM NODE_LIST nl WHERE nl.ID = n.ID)
);
```

**Request**

I'd like to have just one `NODE_LIST` or simplify the query as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/apsg/src/tpc/db2z_createcte.html says:

> You can use common table expressions before a fullselect in a CREATE VIEW statement. This technique is useful if you need to use the results of a common table expression in more than one query.

I read this to mean that unless you create a view, you can use a CTE only in the query in which you define it.

Comment: Well this would help from a definition point of view - not for a improved performance. I suggest using a temporary table instead.